# Google CDN setting up Cookies, why?

Tags: jquery, cdn

Isn't this sort of a thumb-rule? Shouldn't this be served from a cookie-less domain?

> Serve the following static resources from a domain that doesn't set
>   cookies:
>
> - http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js

Anyone know any alternative URL that Google would use to by-pass the Cookies?

---

**Edit:** To anyone seeing this page. The issue was a Firefox/Firebug crazyness. As soon as I cleared the cache all went back to normal.

Comment: You sure it's got cookies...? I'm pretty sure Google has that separate domain for the very reason of not having any cookies in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the few clients I tried, this is all that came back in the response headers. You are seeing cookies being set in the response?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
Last-Modified: Mon, 15 Feb 2010 23:30:12 GMT
Date: Mon, 20 Sep 2010 16:05:17 GMT
Expires: Tue, 20 Sep 2011 16:05:17 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Server: sffe
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
Age: 20
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Comment: I was... cleared the browser and voilà... exactly your response. Archived as a Firefox/Firebug weirdo. Thks.